# Multiple search query

Tags: objectbox

Previously I really liked this package, because it was very helpful and easy to understand

```
@Entity()
class Person {
    int id;
    String name;
    final address = ToOne<Address>();
}

@Entity()
class Address {
    int id;
    String street;
    String zip;
}
```

I want to find the name of the Person and the street of the Address, please help...

Thank you very much

Is there something wrong with my code ?

```
box.query(Person_.name.contains(search_value))..link(Person_.address, Address_.street.contains(search_value));
```

When I search, the value doesn't appear, even though the character I'm looking for is in either the name of the Person or the street of the Address

Comment: "is in either the name of the Person or the street" -> you are assuming that the two conditions are ORed, but they are not. Both conditions must apply (AND). Thus, to get what you wanted, you could have e.g. two queries (one for Person and another one with the link to Address).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, does that mean it can't be just one query ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok, sorry if it's not too detailed for the explanation, example :

List<Person> person = [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Jaka',
      'address': {
        'id': 11,
        'street': 'Jln Mawar 001',
      },
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'Gilang',
      'address': {
        'id': 12,
        'street': 'Jln Pegangsaan 002',
      },
    },
    {
      'id': 3,
      'name': 'Heru',
      'address': {
        'id': 13,
        'street': 'Jln Melati 003',
      },
    },
  ];

when i type 'ang' it only shows id:2, How to ?

Comment: Yes, using two queries should do the trick.

Comment: okay I'll try it first, thank you for the advice given, good luck

Comment: https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#notable-conditions check out this